# Disprove $f(n) = 2^{2n}$ is $O(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Disprove $f(n) = 2^{2n}$ is $O(2^n)$

Informally I know that this means we have to show that $2^{2n}$ grows much faster than $2^n$.

More formally, I know that we need to show that for any $N$, there is a constant $c>0$, so that for all $n>N$ such that $2^{2n}>c\cdot 2^n$.

I am not sure how to derive $N$ and a fixed constant $c$ in order to disprove this proposition.  Can anybody show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{2^{2n}}{2^n}=2^n$$

Comment: I feel like I am close to understanding, but not quite there.  Can you explain how that helps me solve the problem?

Comment: @OmarN From your last inequality, $2^{2n}>c2^n$, we find that $2^n>c$, which is true because $2^n$ takes on all values from $0$ to $\infty$, which is clearly greater than C.